# How to update American Megatrends bios

Tags: bios

I have a American Megatrends F8 31/05/2012 v2.7 bios which I need to update for my new graphics card. Where can I find the newest bios for this version?

I attempted to run the AMI bios updater utility but it failed with an error "Flash part is not supported".

I downloaded it from here: https://ami.com/en/download-license-agreement/?DownloadFile=AMIBIOS8_AMI_Firmware_Update_Utility.zip

I'm not even sure if this is the right tool for me. There support documentation seems limited. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You typically would download it from the OEM of the hardware vendor.  The generic tool you downloaded isn't applicable to your device and cannot be used.

Comment: If you don't know about the details I'd recommend not to update BIOS. If you've done something wrong the motherboard will become unusable.

Answer (score 2):

See your motherboard manufacturer and its model. Then, on the official website of the manufacturer search for your model and see if they have a updated version of the BIOS you currently have

To check your BIOS currently running run this on cmd:

> wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion

BIOS installation varies (they can include a Windows application that does that for you or you need to create a bootable USB with the BIOS files).

*Be aware*: Updating BIOS is an advanced process and if you do it wrong you can break the whole system. Proceed with caution, read the motherboard manual before anything else.